# How to change value of base template based on different user in Flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

The Flask app connects a user table whose structure is

```
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| usr     | psd   | role   | company |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| ab_tom  | ab    | viewer | AB      |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| cd_tom  | cd    | admin  | CD      |
+---------+-------+--------+---------+
```

The all pages of the web app are based on the base template and I need the nav bar show the company name based on the login user, no matter how deep the user goes into the app. All pages are extended from the base tamplate.
The Jinja2 argument where I put the variable is

```
<a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{{url_for('select_function')}}">Time {{ titleBind }}Logo</a>
```

The function `select_function()` shows all the values from a dictionary.
Is there a way that I can change the value of `titleBind` once for all by login instead of passing the value each time using `url_for()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in the session object. Jinja2 can access the session object in the template as `session.titleBind` or `session['titleBind']`

[This example in the flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/tutorial/templates/) shows you an example of using this

Updated:
I assumed you know how the session object works otherwise you can read up in the [quickstart guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)